# Find the field line to the vector field

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

**Determine field lines to the vector field V(x, y) = (x, −y)**

> This is how far I've come. The field line's derivative and the Field
> function should always be equal for all x & y.

Lets say the field line is $f(x,y)=(x,y)$ and of course we parameterize them and then get $f'(x,y)=(x'(t), y'(t))$. And lets say $u(t)$ is the size of the vector.

$(x'(t), y'(t)) = u(t) (x(t), -y(t)) <=> x'(t)= u(x(t))$
and
$y'(t)= -u(t)y(t)$.

> After multiplying both equations with x and y, I simplify the entire
> thing to:

$yx'+xy'=0$.

> Have I done right so far? If yes how do I continue solving.

By the way the answer is that the field lines are hyperbolas.

Comment: What does $f’(x,y)$ mean?

Answer (score 1):

$xy'+x'y =(xy)' =0$

Integrate both sides:
$xy = c    $
$y = \dfrac{c}{x}  $
Where $c$ is a constant
It is indeed the equation of hyperbola,unless $c =0,$which then will be the x axis